# node.js proxy app in docker behind nginx proxy

Tags: node.js, nginx, docker, proxy

I am trying to setup nginx proxy to node.js proxy to aws elasticsearch app in a docker.

```
nginx version: nginx/1.10.0 - installed on the machine, not in docker
Docker version 1.12.5, build 047e51b/1.12.5
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
docker run -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY -p 127.0.0.1:9200:9200 mydocker/es_kibana_proxy -b 0.0.0.0 search-elasticsearch-dev-tdxka.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com
```

netstat -nlp:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/systemd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8431/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9200          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7963/docker-proxy-c
```

Its works when I run the container on my local computer and access it via the browser without nginx - `http://127.0.0.1:9200/_plugin/kibana/`

`nginx.conf:`

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    #gzip  on;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

`conf.d]# cat default.conf`

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name nginx.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /es-kibana-dev { proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9200/_plugin/kibana/; }

    location /es-dev {

      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9200;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

I can see kibana page when I go to `nginx.mydomain.com/es-kibana-dev`, but its stuck and I get 404, and the below errors in error.log:

```
[error] 8234#8234: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/styles/main.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 12.12.12.1, server: nginx.mydomain.com, request: "GET /styles/main.css?_b=7562 HTTP/1.1", host: "nginx.mydomain.com", referrer: "http://nginx.mydomain.com/es-kibana-dev"

error] 8234#8234: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/bower_components/requirejs/require.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 12.12.12.1, server: nginx.mydomain.com, request: "GET /bower_components/requirejs/require.js?_b=7562 HTTP/1.1", host: "", referrer: "http://nginx.mydomain.com/es-kibana-dev"

[error] 8234#8234: *3 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/require.config.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 12.12.12.1, server: nginx.mydomain.com, request: "GET /require.config.js?_b=7562 HTTP/1.1", host: "nginx.mydomain.com", referrer: "http://nginx.mydomain.com/es-kibana-dev"

[error] 8234#8234: *4 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/images/initial_load.gif" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 12.12.12.1, server: nginx.mydomain.com, request: "GET /images/initial_load.gif HTTP/1.1", host: "nginx.mydomain.com", referrer: "http://nginx.mydomain.com/es-kibana-dev"
```

I tried to set up differently the proxy to es index, and I see that when I go to `http://nginx.mydomain.com/es-dev` :

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"es-dev","index":"es-dev"}],"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"es-dev","index":"es-dev"},"status":404}
```

I can see the the index properly on my localhost - `http://127.0.0.1:9200`, without nginx.

```
{
  "name" : "Morbius",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch-dev",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "2.3.2",
    "build_hash" : "72aa8010df1a4a359c9c588",
    "build_timestamp" : "2016-11-14T15:59:50Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "5.5.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

I have a feeling the problems are with the nginx configuration.

any suggestions are welcome,

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP *privare_ip;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connect "Keep-Alive";
        proxy_set_header Proxy-Connection "Keep-Alive";
        proxy_set_header Authorization "";
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9200;
        }
```

Its works for both

```
http://my.domain.com/ => http://127.0.0.1:9200;
http://my.domain.com/_plugin/kibana  => http://127.0.0.1:9200/_plugin/kibana
```

Answer (score 1):

The following blocks work for me:

```
location /es-kibana-dev {
  rewrite ^/es-kibana-dev/(.*) /_plugin/kibana/$1 break;
  proxy_pass http://localhost:9200;
}

location /es-dev {
  rewrite ^/es-dev/(.*) /$1 break;
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9200;
}
```

Visit (Don't forget the trailing slash):

- http://nginx.mydomain.com/es-dev/ (for elasticsearch)
- http://nginx.mydomain.com/es-kibana-dev/ (for kibana)

Comment: thanks, but I still have the same issue, if you want to know, I am using this docker container `https://github.com/santthosh/aws-es-kibana` and I want to access via nginx, if I curl inside the machine to local host `curl http://localhost:9200` I can see the index, but from the browser I see errors, another idea ? thank you!

Comment: this is what I see from the browser, nginx proxy to the nodejs docker and its proxy to aws es

Comment: `{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"es-dev","index":"es-dev"}],"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"es-dev","index":"es-dev"},"status":404}`

Comment: curl within the server to localhost shows the container its working properly

Comment: `curl http://localhost:9200
{
  "name" : "Warlock",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch-dev",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "2.3.2",
    "build_hash" : "",
    "build_timestamp" : "",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "5.5.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}`

Comment: so I guess somehow the issue with nginx proxy

Comment: Are you sure you made the changes exactly as I mentioned in the answer? Because when I use this and visit http://example.com/es-dev/ , I see the required output with the index name.

Comment: I want nginx proxy => nodejs app proxy to es docker => aws es

Comment: maybe the proxy from nginx doesnt work because the the es configured with access key and private key policy

Comment: @Berlin Let's chat here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134306/nginx-rev-proxy-es

Comment: please ping me when you can access to the chat room again ? thank you, very interesting